# Setting /showincludes property for a single file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies, header-files

I want to find out the header dependency for a single file in my project .I found that /showincludes property can do it .But i just want to enable it for a single file. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can leave the flag for the whole project and compile just that file (right-click the file -> `Compile`)